# reading large .csv file mmap

Tags: julia, mmap

I am trying to open a 3.54GB file

```
s = open("C:/Users/a.bannerman/Desktop/code/TS_data/big.txt","r")
a = Mmap.mmap(s)
```

What is now listed:

```
3802655667-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x30
 0x31
 0x2f
 0x30
 0x32
 0x2f
 0x32
```

Now I am trying to process this file line by line - even subset it which I can do

```
1000-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x30
 0x31
 0x2f
 0x30
 0x32
 0x2f
 0x32
    ⋮
 0x0a
```

How can I resolve the data at the memory addresses (does each memory address point to a single row in the .txt file?) ? Granted on this machine if I resolve all into a matrix,dataframe I would run out of memory.
At this point Id like to iterate over the memory addresses, extract a single row and populate a matrix, dataframe I build, save each block as a .csv, close, free memory then do the next batch. The data itself has n rows, and like 5 columns.

still curious about the above
but this is an answer using `CSV.jl`

```
row_size = 10000
for rows in Iterators.partition(CSV.Rows("C:/Users/a.bannerman/Desktop/code/TS_data/big.txt"), row_size)
    df = DataFrame(rows) # resolve dataframe
    # perform operations on this specific chunk of file
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV.jl does `mmap`

From your post it seems that you want to process a huge CSV file row by row. This can be done using `CSV.Rows` instead of CSV.File.

```
julia> @time CSV.Rows("huge_huge_file.csv")
  0.000654 seconds (1.39 k allocations: 37.500 KiB)
CSV.Rows("huge_huge_file.csv"):
Size: 10
Tables.Schema:
 :elemtype  Union{Missing, PosLenString}
 :elemid    Union{Missing, PosLenString}
 ...
```

Now having a set of rows you can iterate over it like anything else.

Consider this code:

```
df = DataFrame()
for row in CSV.Rows("huge_huge_file.csv")
    push!(df, row)
    nrow(df) > 5 && break
end
```

CSV.jl docs reads:

> CSV.Rows: an alternative approach for consuming delimited data, where the input is only consumed one row at a time, which allows "streaming" the data with a lower memory footprint than CSV.File. Supports many of the same options as CSV.File, except column type handling is a little different. By default, every column type will be essentially Union{Missing, String}, i.e. no automatic type detection is done, but column types can be provided manually. Multithreading is not used while parsing. After constructing a CSV.Rows object, rows can be "streamed" by iterating, where each iteration produces a CSV.Row2 object, which operates similar to CSV.File's CSV.Row type where individual row values can be accessed via row.col1, row[:col1], or row[1]. If each row is processed individually, additional memory can be saved by passing reusebuffer=true, which means a single buffer will be allocated to hold the values of only the currently iterated row. CSV.Rows also supports the Tables.jl interface and can also be passed to valid sink functions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to work with the file in chunks (batches) and not by single rows, you can use `CSV.Chunks`.